# A special class of regular languages: "circular" languages. Is it known?

Tags: automata-theory, formal-languages, graph-theory, coalgebras

We can define a subclass of the regular languages. Fix an alphabet $\Sigma$. Define the "circular" languages (actually, the name already exists to denote a different thing it seems, used in the field of DNA computing. **AFAICT**, that's a different class of languages).

A language $L$ is circular if and only if for all words $w \in \Sigma$, we have:

$w\in L$ if and only if, for all integers $k > 0$ we have $w^k\in L$.

Is this class of languages known? I am interested in:

> - a name for it
> - decidability of the problem, given an automaton (in particular: a DFA), whether the accepted language obeys to the above definition
> - a "nice" characterization (e.g. equational?) of the definition.

Comment: There is a related notion of a cyclic language: they are closed under conjugation and powers.  See http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/Words07/pdf/musikerslides.pdf .

Comment: Just to clarify: You are really only interested in languages which satisfy the cyclicity condition and are, in addition, regular? I ask because the condition itself does not imply regularity - consider, for example, the language of well-matched parentheses.

Comment: Cross-posted on cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/a-special-class-of-regular-languages-circular-languages-is-it-known.

Comment: Yes I am interested in the regular languages that satisfy the condition I spelled. In fact I am only interested in languages that don't contain the empty word, but that's a separate condition. 

Sorry for the crosspost, I did not know what was the most appropriate place for the question. Maybe following up just on cstheory is better.

A language is not circular if L=M* (and L=M+ does not fix this) as Lukasz Grabowski points out with his example.

Yuval Filmus: is what you say that obvious? How do you identify the generators (your "r").


Comment: @vincenzoml: See my answer on cstheory, part 3. As you mention, the correct normal form is a union of $r^+$'s, which unfortunately in general cannot be disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

For deciding whether a language is "circular", you can just take the normalized DFA for the language (where the states correspond to sets of possible different completions).  In that normalized DFA, a language is circular iff the only accept state is the start state, pretty much by definition.

I don't know what you want by a characterization.  A language L has this property iff it is M* for some other language M, but that's not useful..

Comment: The automata construction you suggest always admits the empty string, but he required that $w^k \in L$ for $k > 0$, not $k \geq 0$. So $a+$ would be circular according to his definition, but its minimal automaton would not share accept and start states. 

Comment: Dylan: Are you sure L is circular iff L=M*? The example I have in mind is a langauge on letters <a,b> consisting only of powers of a and of powers of b. AFAIU it is circular, but I can't see why it's M* for some M. 

Comment: In fact, a language is circular iff it's the <i>union</i> of expressions of the form $r^*$.

Comment: Sorry, I was indeed premature.  I'll try to fix this later.  The right characterization should be using r+ rather than r*.

Comment: @Yuval,  he asks that $w$ belongs to $L$ iff $w^k\in L$ for all positive $k$.  Thus the language of all even powers of the letter $a$ is not circular in his sense although it is $(a^2)^*$.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg, why is this language not circular?  The obvious thought (to me) is that the condition would require $a \in L$, but it doesn't really ….

Comment: Oops, I read the statement too quickly. The iff made me think he wanted that some power of w in the language implies w in the language. In other words, I thought he want pure + closed under powers. The iff statement is not really needed then. He wants the implication $w\in L$ implies $w^+\subseteq L$. So Yuval's answer is perfect. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yuval Filmus shows in [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00236-003-0107-x) that it is decidable for a regular language $L$ whether $w\in L\implies w^k\in L$ for all $k>0$.  I would guess there must be an older reference.  On the other hand, a language $L$ is called pure if  $w^k\in L\implies w\in L$.  It was shown by Pedro Silva that purity is decidable for regular languages in http://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/preprints/2002-18.pdf

Since the notion of circular language in the question is the conjunction of these two properties, it is decidable if a regular language is circular.

Comment: Ben, it looks like you gave twice the same link.

Comment: Oops. I will have to hunt the correct one.